# chai-http write after end

Tags: node.js, chai

I have a `server-app` that receives an audio stream from the client. I am trying to test the app using `chai`/`chai-http`, but it gives me this error:

> [Error: write after end]

What's the problem?

Code:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('../server-app');
var should = chai.should();
var fs = require('fs');

chai.use(chaiHttp);


describe('server', function() {
  it('should work..', function (done){
    var req = chai.request(server).post('/speech');
    fs.createReadStream('./test.wav').pipe(req);
    req.end(function (err,res){
        console.log(err);//outputs: [Error: write after end]
        done();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `req.end` before the stream finishes pushing data to the request.

I would do the following:

```
var readstream = fs.createReadStream('./test.wav');
readstream.pipe(req);

readstream.on('close', someFunction);
readstream.on('end', someFunction);
```

and call `req.end` in the **close** or **end** events for the stream. You're calling req.end before either of those events are emitted.

Comment: that didn't help, I put the `req.end` inside the `readstream.on('end')` callback, it keeps giving me errors

Comment: Don't call writableStream.end() on end or close event of redableStream when pipin unles you use options to keep writable open because in this events writableStream is ended    by pipe.

Comment: I have finally fixed that part, but I'm still getting `[SyntaxError: Unexpected token {]` as an error message in req.end, all im doing on client side is: `response.json({"hi":"bye"});`

Comment: Post your new code. I'll check it out once I get off work.

Comment: @Quy I have posted it to a new question since the question has changed now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732114/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token?noredirect=1#comment57213145_34732114

Answer (score 3):

Basically JavaScript is asynchronus and stream or socket connection is synchronus ,Once you created a stream you have to wait for the stream to close to make another request

In your case the req.end getting executed once you opened the stream

Three options available to make it to be work

1. Try with chai agent
2. Put your code in the stream close because both chai.end and stream end seems to be same for your scenario
3. put req.end inside setTimeOut (Did not tried may be for worst case)

Answer (score 2):

When piping, by default, `end()` is called on the destination when the source stream emits `'end'` event. So you don't have to call `end()` by youself.

Suscribe to the `'finish'` and `'error'` event of the destination stream to control when the work it is done or when a error happens:

```
 fs.createReadStream('./test.wav').pipe(req);
 req.on('error', (err) => {console.log(err);});
 req.on('finish',() => {done();});
```

If you want to keep the writer (`req`) open you can set `end option` to false when piping:

`fs.createReadStream('./test.wav').pipe(req, options = {end = false});` but keep in mind that 'finish' event wont be fired up by the pipe.

Comment: what's the difference between `finish` and `end` ?

Comment: Writable streams has no end event.

Comment: `finish` never gets called, only my `end` does.

Comment: In the redable or the writable stream?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html here you can see the evets of writable and redable streams. Writable has finish and is called when pipe calls writable.end()