# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: node.js, stream, chai

I am trying to write a chai test where all I do is just stream some audio and get a simple response back: `{}` , for some reason I'm getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` when ever I pipe my `fs` stream to `req`, if I remove the piping and I don't have that stream the test works fine.

server code:

```
router.post('/', function (clientRequest, clientResponse) {
    clientRequest.on('end', function () {//when done streaming audio
        console.log('im at the end>>>>>');
        clientResponse.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //I've tried removing that: same result
        clientResponse.json({});
        clientResponse.end(); //I've tried removing that: same result
    }); //end clientRequest.on('end',)
});
```

test code:

```
var app = require('./app');

describe('server', function() {
    this.timeout(10000);
    it('should WORK!!!"', function (done){
        var req = chai.request(app).post('/speech');

        var readStream = fs.createReadStream('./test.wav');
        readStream.on('end',function(){
            console.log("readStream end>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            req.end(function (err, res) {
                console.log("req.end callback>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                done();
            });
        });
        readStream.pipe(req);
    });
});
```

error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
     at Object.parse (native)
     at _stream_readable.js:908:16
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, if you do `.json(...)` you are already "ending" the response, so you don't need `clientResponse.end();` at all.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, that does not change the result tho

Comment: Could you please tell us which line of code is 908? Honestly, this code you are showing seems not having any kind of unexpected `{`... It could be in another file...

Comment: line 90 is in _stream_readable.js , it's an internal javascript file https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L908 , I don't know how much of a help would that be for you

Comment: Is this full error message? Looks like a part of is cut. Can you also provide full server code? Especially body parsing stuff.

Comment: this is the full server code, this is the full server code, all I'm missing is some `require`s and `express().use(app).listen..`

Comment: Increase your stack trace and it'll tell you exactly where the SyntaxError is. I usually use the npm `longjohn` module to increase the stack trace in development environments. https://www.npmjs.com/package/longjohn

Comment: @Quy I've added in the server: `require('longjohn').async_trace_limit = -1;` which if i'm not mistaken would make the stack trace unlimited, that didn't change the error

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace ?

Comment: @Quy I'm sorry for not making myself clear, the full stack trace is in the question, longjohn did NOT give me any more information.

Comment: I agree with @nbro, that exception is unlikely to be coming from this part of the code. try to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it's full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Error analysis

The code in general is actually works and the problem is somewhere inside the superagent.

Actually question actually is missing some details, so I had to guess missing parts, like `chai.request(app)` is done using [chai-http](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http), which in turn uses [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) to perform http requests.

And the problem seems to be somewhere inside the superagent, I was able to reproduce your error with a bit more info (not sure why I got longer trace):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {                                                                                                                      
 at Object.parse (native)                                                                                                                                     
 at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/project/path/node_modules/chai-http/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:9:2
 at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)                                                                                                      
 at _stream_readable.js:920:16                                                                                                                                
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

And I was able to check that JSON parses tries to parse double response. Like if server responses with `{}`, the parser has `{}{}`, or if server responses with `{"a":"b"}`, the parser has `{"a":"b"}{"a":"b"}`.
You can check this yourself inserting `console.log(res.text)` before [this line](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/node/parsers/json.js#L8) (locally this file is under node_modules/chai-http/node_modules/superagent).

Also if I move the `readStream.pipe(req);` just above the line with `var readStream`:

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('./test.wav');
readStream.pipe(req);
readStream.on('end',function(){
    ...
```

Then the test passes, but outputs 'double callback!' - it is also [printed by superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/node/index.js#L799) and confirms that something goes wrong with it.

### The fix

It is not complex to do the same thing without `chai-http` and `superagent`.

First, the server-side code. It is changed a bit - instead of `clientRequest.on('end', ...` I pipe it to the write stream. This way I also can check that the file was actually transferred:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

module.exports = app;

app.post('/speech', function (clientRequest, clientResponse) {
    console.log('speech');
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./test_out.wav');
    //for me on('end'... doesn't work (it infinitely waits for event
    //probably because the file is small and it finishes before we
    //get here
    clientRequest.pipe(writeStream).on('finish', function() {
        console.log('im at the end>>>>>');
        clientResponse.json({'a':'b'});
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("App started");
});
```

And the test:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var chai = require('chai');
var http = require('http');

// Require our application and create a server for it
var app = require('./unexpected');
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(0);
var addr = server.address();

describe('server', function() {
    this.timeout(10000);
    it('should WORK!!!"', function (done){
        // setup read stream
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream('./test.wav');
        readStream.on('end',function(){
            console.log("readStream end>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        });
        // setup the request
        var request = http.request({
            'host': 'localhost',
            'port': addr.port,
            'path': '/speech',
            'method': 'POST'
        });
        // now pipe the read stream to the request
        readStream.pipe(request).on('finish', function() {
            console.log("pipe end>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        });
        // get the response and finish when we get all the response data
        request.on('response', function(response) {
            console.log("request end>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            response.on('data', function(data) {
                console.log('response data: ' + data);
            });
            response.on('end', function(data) {
                console.log('done!');
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I think code should be self-explanatory, I just use the standard node [http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) to do the job.

Comment: `var server = http.createServer(app);` that's the line i've been looking for

Comment: so you are saying that something is wrong with `superagent` and i should post an issue on their github?

Comment: @bubakazouba Somehow superagent's request text is doubled (although there is only one real request to the server). So even if the actual problem is in chai-http or in the original test code, I think superagent should not allow such situation.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to replace this command

```
clientResponse.json({});
```

with

```
clientResponse.send({});
```

Comment: i tried that, didnt work, i tried also putting clientResponse.end(); after the send, didn't help either